# Set tick mark distance within for loop for ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, yticks

##### Problem

I have a for loop that produces a set of graphs that are all the same but for different locations.

I want to be able to control the tick marks so that the the distance between each tick mark is the same for each plot. I don't want hard set limits as each graph is too different. I'd like the interval distance between each tick to be the same, so the graphs are more comparable. i.e. I'd like all the y axes to be relative to one another.

NOTE: I don't want them all the have the same axes, I just want them to be relative. The distance between two ticks is the same on each plot.

##### Plots currently look like this:

[image]

##### Current Code

```
j = 1   # counter for plot title and index
for (datTime in chapel){
  plotName <- names(chapel)[j]
  j = j+1
  
  datTime <- datTime %>% 
    filter((DateTime > as.POSIXct("2020-03-05 00:00:00")) & (DateTime < as.POSIXct("2023-03-04 00:00:00")))
  
  plot <- 
    datTime %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=DateTime)) +
    geom_point(aes(y=mAOD), col='grey') +
    geom_smooth(aes(y=mAOD), col='black', se=FALSE, span=0.1, method="loess") +
    geom_hline(yintercept=datTime$groundLevel, col='dark green') +
    theme_classic() +
    labs(y='Water Depth (mAOD)', x=NULL) +
    ggtitle(plotTitles[[plotName]][1]) + 
    scale_x_datetime(
      breaks=seq(update(min(datTime$DateTime), month = 1, day = 1), max(datTime$DateTime), 
                 by= "1 year"), date_labels="%Y") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels=scaleFUN,  limits = c(81.5, 84.8)) +
    theme(text=element_text(size=20, family='Calibri Light')) +
    theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 1), 'cm')) +
    theme(axis.title.y=element_text(margin=margin(t=0, r=20, b=0, l=0))) +
    theme(axis.title.x=element_text(margin=margin(t=20, r=0, b=0, l=0))) +
    theme(axis.title.y.right=element_text(margin=margin(t=0, r=0, b=0, l=20)))
  
  plotlist_controlSites[[plotName]] <- plot
}
```

##### Dataframe

The data frames each have a datetime column and a mAOD column (all values vary between 81 and 84). There are 10 plots in total.

This is the top 10 lines of the first dataframe in the list "chapel":

```
structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1576022400, 1576108800, 
1576195200, 1576281600, 1576368000, 1576454400), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), mAOD = c(NA, 82.4402870833333, 82.5335010416667, 
82.5776004166667, 82.5414891666667, 82.505000625)), row.names = c(447L, 
488L, 529L, 570L, 611L, 652L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Instead of making a plot for each element of the `chapel` list it may be easier to add the name to each element, `bind_rows` and `facet_wrap`.
e.g. `chapel %>% map2(names(chapel), ~mutate(.x, name=.y))) %>% ggplot() ... + facet_wrap(~name)`

Comment: @RobinGertenbach will this actually help with my axes problem?

Comment: Yes, `facet_wrap` will automatically align the axes unless you free them (see [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_wrap.html)), sorry forgot to clarify that

Comment: @RobinGertenbach Its producing errors for me. I've edited the question to include an example of the data frame in the list.

Comment: Forgot the `bind_rows` call in the example, see my comment below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by finding the max range of the data on the y axis. Then  Setting the ylims to the minimum y value and the min + the largest range in the data. Now all the y axis are relative to one another and plots can be compared visually.

I included this in the for loop above the plot

```
min <- min(datTime$mAOD, na.rm=T) 
  max <- (min + 1.8)
  top <- max(datTime$mAOD, na.rm=T)
  range <- (top - min)
  print(range)
```

And added in this to the ggplot.

```
scale_y_continuous(labels=scaleFUN, breaks=seq(70, 90, by=0.5), limits = c(min, max))
```

Maybe a slight hack, but it did the job.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Taking your example data.frame as `df` and creating a list that looks like `chapel`

```
chapel <- list(
  basic = df,
  plus_ten = mutate(df, mAOD = mAOD + 10),
  plus_40 = mutate(df, mAOD = mAOD + 40)
)

chapel %>%
  map2(names(chapel), ~ mutate(.x, title = .y)) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  ggplot(aes(DateTime, mAOD)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  facet_wrap(~title)
```

[image]